# Не записывается/прибавляется значение в базе-данных (sqlite3)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3, python-telegram-bot

Не записывается значение в БД.

Код из **bot.py** (код бота)

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
    #tmpconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    #tmpcursor = tmpconnect.cursor()

    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))

    #tmpcursor.execute("UPDATE users SET number = number + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (number, user_id))

    db.add_energetik(number, message.from_user.id)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```

Код из **bd.py** (код базы данных).

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
            
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.connection.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def add_energetik(self, user_id, number):
            with self.connection:
                return self.connection.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `number` = `number` + ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (number, user_id,))
```

Сам бот работает нормально, ошибок не выдает и БД подключается нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вижу строчки self.db_file.commit() ну или что то вроде этого

Comment: @АртемТоршин Все равно не записывается.

Comment: Попробуйте расставьте принты повсюду,если исключение не кидает значит что то по идее возвращает None

Comment: @АртемТоршин оказывается проблема была в данной строке: def add_energetik(self, number, user_id):
Надо было user_id, и number поменять местами. И все заработало 